# Isn't this question a better fit for Workplace.SE?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close

[Comparing one's self to others during interviews](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/89266/comparing-ones-self-to-others-during-interviews)

Isn't this question a better fit for Workplace.SE?

I just don't see how this is specific to programmers or programming.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly.

However, it's a relatively high scoring question with 14 answers - one of which has been accepted - asked over a year ago.

Migrating old questions - especially high scoring ones - is not a good idea as it skews the reputation on the target site. Users who aren't very active on the target site suddenly get a reputation boost. The people who voted might not be experts in the subject matter of the target site (less likely in this case) and might not even have accounts on the site.

If you think the question is off topic please vote for it to be closed and/or flag it for moderator attention, but it's highly unlikely that we'll migrate.

Comment: +1: OK. That's fair.

Comment: @JimG. If we migrated the question today, it'd be the 15th most voted question on The Workplace, without their community having any involvement in it. We really don't want that, The Workplace community has to grow on its own, by their rules, etc. If it's a stellar question for The Workplace, I'm sure it will be re-asked there at some point.